# Vue Material md-input different from example

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I want to use vue material for my app,
i already install vue-material in my app, and do this in my main.js:

```
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
```

but, when i use some component from vue-material in my index page like this:

```
<template>
   <md-field>
    <label>Username</label>
    <md-input v-model="username"></md-input>
   </md-field>
   <md-field>
    <label>Password</label>
    <md-input v-model="password"></md-input>
   </md-field>
</template>
```

my page show:

[image]

when i visit example form input in codepen, form input should like this:

[image]

whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 6):

This happened with me too,

To fix it, you just need to set a theme for your app like this:

`import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'`

Comment: Caio, would you be willing to look at another vue-material issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952741/how-to-set-up-flexible-grid-in-vue-material

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a crucial `<form>` tag

As per the [documentation](https://vuematerial.io/components/form), removing some stuff for your use case, you should have at least the following wrapped around those `<md-field>` tags.

```
<form class="md-layout">
  // your form inputs here
</form>
```